# Word interop add-in - changing Window View properties do not affect Revision markup style

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-interop, word-2013

Using an application level add-in, I'm performing some operations on document open that *require revisions (tracked changes) to be rendered inline and not hidden*, so that they are contained within the `Range` of the document. After consulting the documentation, I thought that all I had to do was change the [the view properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKB8Z.png) of the active window: `MarkupMode` claims to do what I want.

But this property seems to be completely disconnected from how revisions display in the document! To test this, I tried toggling the mode manually in a document, and looking at `MarkupMode`, and checking it immediately afterwards in an `onSelectionChange` event handler. I went ahead and tracked a bunch of properties of `ActiveWindow.View`, for good measure. To my surprise and chagrin, when I looked at the locals with changes rendered inline:

[image: before]

[image: before values]

*... and compared the values to those with changes hidden:*

[image: after]

[image: after values]

Nothing changed! What gives? Am I not looking at the right property/properties to ensure that changes are rendered inline? Is Microsoft completely incapable of writing meaningful documentation? I'll point out that I tried to make the property change in code as well, to see if the rendering of revisions would change, with no success. I would appreciate any feedback.

**Edit:** Simple code to duplicate issue:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.WindowSelectionChange += application_WindowSelectionChange;
}

private void application_WindowSelectionChange(Selection sel)
{
    var testDoc = sel.Document;

    var test = new
    {
        testDoc.ActiveWindow.View,
        testDoc.ActiveWindow.View.ShowRevisionsAndComments,
        testDoc.ActiveWindow.View.ShowInsertionsAndDeletions,
        testDoc.ActiveWindow.View.MarkupMode,
        testDoc.ActiveWindow.View.RevisionsMode
    };
}
```

**Edit 2:** Beyond this contrived example, I need to have control over the markup style of Revisions because I am searching for text on `DocumentOpen` that may include text that is present as `Revision` objects. More specifically, I am attempting to do the following, using the above text (with text "powerful way to help you prove " deleted in a revision):

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.DocumentOpen += application_DocumentOpen;
}

private void application_DocumentOpen(Document doc)
{
    // expected text, as taken from screengrab example above. Includes
    //  text removed in a revision
    string expectedText = "Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.";

    // make sure that we're in print view
    if (doc.ActiveWindow.View.Type != WdViewType.wdPrintView)
    {
        doc.ActiveWindow.View.Type = WdViewType.wdPrintView;
    }

    // attempt to ensure that document revisions are marked up inline. Does not accomplish anything
    doc.ActiveWindow.View.MarkupMode = WdRevisionsMode.wdInLineRevisions;        
    // attempt to locate text. Will fail if revisions are not marked up inline (deletion is not part of document content range otherwise)
    var locatedRange = doc.Content.OccurrenceOfText(expectedText);
}

// extension method to locate text inside a range. Searching entire Content in this example
private static Range OccurrenceOfText(this Range rng, string text)
{
    rng.Find.Forward = true;
    rng.Find.Format = false;

    rng.Find.Execute(text);

    if (!rng.Find.Found)
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to locate text! Are Revisions marked up inline?");
    }

    // return brand new range containing located content
    return rng.Document.Range(rng.Start, rng.End);
}
```

**Edit 3:** As Cindy made clear, my problem was that I was using the wrong property: I needed to use the `View.RevisionsFilter.Markup` property to make the change. Additionally, an issue that I hadn't diagnosed is that depending on the View properties, it is entirely possible that the `Range` returned from a search performed as I do returns a `Text` property that is different than the text that was searched with. This can happen if `Revision` objects are present inside the `Range`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax you're using: var test = new { ... }. Testing in-process (VBA) changing the properties you list does work, so it could have something to do with how you've constructed your code. You mention this should run on DocumentOpen - it's possible that when your code is called the document is not quite ready to receive these commands. Could you provide exact repro steps for the real problem?

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks for the response, Cindy. You're correct that this isn't how I'm attempting to interact with the `MarkupMode` property in my code, but even this contrived example demonstrates my problem, and is easy to reproduce. Using the anonymous object construct I provided isn't necessary; it just shows the properties I'm looking at, and their values when debugging. You can just as easily simply inspect the properties of `Document.ActiveWindow.View`.

Comment: @CindyMeister A quick description: After toggling inline revision markup on/off, as shown in the screengrabs I provided, and subsequently inspecting the properties of `Document.ActiveWindow.View`, whether you do that by triggering a `SelectionChange` event as I do, or some other mechanism, you can verify that none of the properties I listed (`ShowRevisionsAndComments`, `ShowInsertionsAndDeletions`, `MarkupMode`, `RevisionsMode`) ever change. Which led me to believe that perhaps I'm not looking at the right property.

Comment: I'd still be interested in repro steps for how you intend to actually USE the properties. It's possible that Word is returning "false" information because things haven't actually taken effect at the time the event you want to use to monitor this triggers. Important is whether the properties can actually be set in VSTO at the point you require them...

Comment: @CindyMeister fair enough. Example of my usage provided in an edit on my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me. What I did:

1. Created a test document. Used =rand() ->Press Enter to put some text in the document. Copied in the phrase, changing "powerful" to "useful".
2. Turned on track changes and made some changes, including selecting "useful" and typing "powerful".
3. Made sure the changes were displaying in balloons and the "Original" view of the mark-up was being shown.
4. Saved and closed the document.
5. Put a break-point on the line that calls OccurrenceOfText, then F5 to start the add-in in debug mode.
6. Opened the saved document. The Open event fired. I checked the values of the View.Markup and View.RevisionsView - they had changed to inline and "Final". Stepped through the rest of the code and it executed correctly (found the occurrence).

I needed to modify your code slightly since I don't have your "wrapper". I also changed the way OccurrenceOfText returns the Range: no need to do it in the complicated manner you use...

I note that you do not appear to set View.RevisionsView - perhaps this is why you're not seeing the result you expect?

```
 private void Application_DocumentOpen(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc)
  {
            //Test revisions
    // expected text, as taken from screengrab example above. Includes
    //  text removed in a revision
    string expectedText = "Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.";

    // make sure that we're in print view
    if (doc.ActiveWindow.View.Type != Word.WdViewType.wdPrintView)
    {
        doc.ActiveWindow.View.Type = Word.WdViewType.wdPrintView;
    }

    // attempt to ensure that document revisions are marked up inline. Does not accomplish anything
    Word.View vw = doc.ActiveWindow.View;
    vw.MarkupMode = Word.WdRevisionsMode.wdInLineRevisions;
    vw.RevisionsView = Word.WdRevisionsView.wdRevisionsViewFinal;      
    // attempt to locate text. Will fail if revisions are not marked up inline (deletion is not part of document content range otherwise)
    var locatedRange = OccurrenceOfText(doc.Content, expectedText);
}

// extension method to locate text inside a range. Searching entire Content in this example
private static Word.Range OccurrenceOfText(Word.Range rng, string text)
{
    rng.Find.Forward = true;
    rng.Find.Format = false;

    rng.Find.Execute(text);

    if (!rng.Find.Found)
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to locate text! Are Revisions marked up inline?");
    }

    // return brand new range containing located content
    return rng;  //.Document.Range(rng.Start, rng.End);
 }
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't consider using the `RevisionsView` property. This doesn't exactly fix my issue. You're looking for the final markup, but I am attempting to do a text search on the string containing _both_ the original and new text, exactly as it appears when revisions are rendered in the document inline. The string I would then be looking for is: "Video provides a powerful useful way to help you prove your point." In the context of the document, "powerful" underlined, and "useful" struck through. Is this possible?

Comment: That's exactly the result the code I posted returned. So, yes, it's possible and it's odd you Aren't getting that, which is why I listed the steps I used in such detail.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I misunderstood how revisions are searched over -- I assumed that `expectedText` would always equal the text returned by `Range.Text`, when it fact it doesn't, when revisions are in the document. Thanks for your assistance and patience.